# using javax validator or spring validator how to have separate error messages for separate fields of same type

Tags: bean-validation, spring-validator

Currently I have a spring boot application and for validation of POJOs i am using javax validator.We have rest apis in the application.

**My question is** : How can I have separate error messages for separate fields of same type.

**Explanation with example** : In reference to the sample code below : If a1.name is not present have a separate error message (ERROR1) and if a2.name is not present have a separate error message (ERROR2)

My POJO, with the javax validator annotation looks something like :

```
public class A{
 @NotNull
 private String name;
 @NotNull
 private String age;
 //..getters and setters
}

public class B{
 @Valid
 private A a1;
 @Valid
 private A a2;
 }
```

My rest controller looks like:

```
@RestController
public class Controller1{
 @GetMapping(value="/abc")
 public void api1(@Valid @RequestBody B b){...}
}
```

I tried to use group but javax @valid annotaion doesnt supports group.
Another option i tried to use spring @Validated annotation but problem with that is it cant be applied on fields.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Bean validation groups are not designed to meet this use case.

If you call your REST service like that :

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -d '{"a1":{}, "a2":{}}}' http://localhost:8080/abc
```

The response is :

```
{
       "timestamp":"2017-11-10T17:22:07.534+0000",
       "status":400,
       "error":"Bad Request",
       "exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
       "errors":[
          {
             "codes":["NotNull.b.a1.name", "NotNull.a1.name", "NotNull.name", "NotNull.java.lang.String", "NotNull"],
             "arguments":[
                {
                   "codes":["b.a1.name", "a1.name" ],
                   "arguments":null,
                   "defaultMessage":"a1.name",
                   "code":"a1.name"
                }
             ],
             "defaultMessage":"may not be null",
             "objectName":"b",
             "field":"a1.name",
             "rejectedValue":null,
             "bindingFailure":false,
             "code":"NotNull"
          },
          {
             "codes":["NotNull.b.a2.age", "NotNull.a2.age", "NotNull.age", "NotNull.java.lang.String", "NotNull"],
             "arguments":[
                {
                   "codes":[ "b.a2.age", "a2.age"],
                   "arguments":null,
                   "defaultMessage":"a2.age",
                   "code":"a2.age"
                }
             ],
             "defaultMessage":"may not be null",
             "objectName":"b",
             "field":"a2.age",
             "rejectedValue":null,
             "bindingFailure":false,
             "code":"NotNull"
          },
          {
             "codes":[ "NotNull.b.a1.age", "NotNull.a1.age", "NotNull.age", "NotNull.java.lang.String", "NotNull"],
             "arguments":[
                {
                   "codes":["b.a1.age", "a1.age"],
                   "arguments":null,
                   "defaultMessage":"a1.age",
                   "code":"a1.age"
                }
             ],
             "defaultMessage":"may not be null",
             "objectName":"b",
             "field":"a1.age",
             "rejectedValue":null,
             "bindingFailure":false,
             "code":"NotNull"
          },
          {
             "codes":["NotNull.b.a2.name", "NotNull.a2.name", "NotNull.name", "NotNull.java.lang.String", "NotNull"],
             "arguments":[
                {
                   "codes":["b.a2.name", "a2.name"],
                   "arguments":null,
                   "defaultMessage":"a2.name",
                   "code":"a2.name"
                }
             ],
             "defaultMessage":"may not be null",
             "objectName":"b",
             "field":"a2.name",
             "rejectedValue":null,
             "bindingFailure":false,
             "code":"NotNull"
          }
       ],
       "message":"Validation failed for object='b'. Error count: 4",
       "path":"/api/profile/abc"
    }
```

If you look closely you'll see that the response says that you get four validation errors and, for each one, validation details like the constraint, object and targeted field, for example : `NotNull.b.a1.name`.

It's the responsability of the view (REST client) to interpolate this detailled response to display the appropriate validation messages.

---

Sometimes it's not an option to interpolate messages on the client side. In this case you can add a custom "validation errors" handler with Spring. Something like that :

```
@RestController
public class Controller1 {

    // This assumes that Spring i18n is properly configured
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        for (FieldError fieldError: fieldErrors) {
            String fieldPath = fieldError.getField();
            String messageCode = fieldError.getCode() + "." + fieldPath;
            String validationMessage = messageSource.getMessage(messageCode, new Object[]{fieldError.getRejectedValue()}, Locale.getDefault());

            // add the validation message, for example "NotNull.a1.name" => "a should not be null"
            errors.put(fieldError.getField(), validationMessage);
        }

        return errors;
    } 


    @GetMapping(value="/abc")
    public void api1(@Valid @RequestBody B b){
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sebastein

Thanks a lot for your reply.

I have already been using a solution that is somewhat similar to what you suggested. So I am maintaining a map of a [fieldName , message]. The fieldName contains the parentVariableName.fieldName. We can get this from the FieldError.getField(). And then using the fieldName we can get the respective message from the map.

I was just eager to find out if javax validation has provided some easier way to handle the above explained scenario.

Comment: I see. Again, I think you will not find a solution with Bean validation only. But Spring Validation works at a higher level and provides a solution because you can override the default response returned when there is a validation error. You can therefore return a custom response that could be a map of the field paths as keys and validation messages as values.